WiFi router using another WiFi network to reach Internet
Is there an off-the-shelf way to create a private WiFI network (with firewall to block inbound connections), which uses another WiFi network to connect to the Internet?
This sounds like a "WiFi Extender", but I read Does a Wi-Fi range extender create a separate network? and it seems to say that most extenders are a strange hybrid, where the NAT address ranges must be disjoint and clients of the extender are directly addressable from upstream, which I do not want..
Do there exist WiFi routers with two radios,where one can be used for the Internet "uplink" ?
I need the exact equivalent of connecting a WiFi router's "WAN" port into a wired LAN port on an "upstream" router, to create my own completely independent NAT network with firewall; but instead of connecting with a cable it would use the WiFi offered by the upstream network.
The real problem I want to solve is this: I live in a retirement community which provides fast free WiFi-only Internet -- no wired connections allowed (if they were, I could just plug in an ordinary WiFi router and be done).  I need to use a wireless printer, and could put it on the campus WiFi but then it would be visible to everyone and people are likely to print to my printer by mistake, etc.  Also I'm uncomfortable exposing my computer to a LAN with 85 other old people, some of which are likely to have devices infected with viruses trying to propagate over the network. The campus WiFI does not have Client Isolation enabled and they won't enable it (I've asked).  So creating my own isolated NAT'd network seems necessary just for security.

Most consumer routers, even the cheapest ones, often can do what you want. Alternative firmwares (e.g. OpenWRT), if supported, can for sure.

@ChanganAuto - can you point me to one specifically?
I've never seen a WiFi router which let you use WiFi for the WAN connection; it would have to let you specify a different SSID & credentials (and possibly radio channels) for the uplink than what is used for the LAN

It's easier to point one that doesn't... You want to familiarize yourself with the bridge mode or any similar wording. Even an entry level TENDA router from 10 years ago does it.

Hmm.  I googled "TENDA bridge mode" and got "In bridge mode, the guest network, parental control, port forwarding, UPnP, DNS, QoS and DHCP server functions become unavailable."  No DHCP implies it makes local clients visible in the upstream network and there isn't any firewall flitering inbetween.
Just to reiterate: I'm looking for a way to have a private local WiFi network, protected by a firewall from any inbound connection requests; which connects to the Internet via another  WiFi network.

I'm not sure that the bridge mode you've found is the one you need. Most commonly, bridge mode does allow the device to receive and rebroadcast the upstream wireless network, but it also accepts the upstream network's DHCP server control, which is what you do not want. You want to connect to the upstream network's wifi signal and then rebroadcast that, but you want your own DHCP server for everything downstream of your device, giving you your own private corner on that network. I'm not sure what this is called. It might be a version of Bridge Mode.

Ok, maybe "receive and rebroadcast the upstream wireless network" indicates that this is not a solution.    If that phrase means the upstream's SSID appears as my local network's SSID (does it?)  then it can not work -- because my local clients could connect to either network unpredictably (and I want them to connect only to my network).  This whole business is too vague and squishy in the details for me to understand if it is something to try.
